# Convert oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPLTZ@71d9d55b to Java TimeStamp

Tags: java, mule

I have a requirement like . In My database table a column type is timestamp with local time zone. When I retrive the value to my MULE application the format is coming as Object. I have used a custom transformer for converting  "oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPLTZ"  to Timestamp in java.

But no luck for me. Can some one help me out on this.

Is there any to convert this object in MULE.

Regards
Vikram

Answer (score 0):

Mule ESB use the apache dbutils framework. You can extend the MapListHandler class to implement your customized transformation.

```
org.apache.commons.dbutils.handlers.MapListHandler
```

Use spring to define your handler and configure the jdbc connector.

**Spring Bean**

```
<spring:beans>
   <spring:bean id="clobMapListHandler" class="com.benasmussen.service.handler.ClobMapListHandler"/>
</spring:beans>
```

**JDBC Connector**

```
<jdbc:connector name="jdbcConnector"  resultSetHandler-ref="clobMapListHandler" />
```

**Source**

The following snippet convert a Oracle CLOB to String.

```
public class ClobMapListHandler extends MapListHandler
{
    @Override
    protected Object handleRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
    {
        Object mapRow = super.handleRow(rs);
        if (mapRow instanceof Map) {
            Map map = (Map) mapRow;
            Set<String> keySet = new HashSet(map.keySet());
            for (String key : keySet)
            {
                Object val = map.get(key);
                if (val instanceof CLOB) 
                {
                    CLOB clob = (CLOB) val;
                    Reader characterStream = clob.getCharacterStream();

                    String value = IOUtils.toString(characterStream);
                    map.put(key, value);                        
                }
            }           
        }
        return mapRow;
    }
}
```